# To find the speed of a beaker that is ejecting fluid, using Bernoulli's equation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, bernoulli-equation

[image]

I wish to mathematically model the speed of a beaker which is ejecting fluid out of a tiny orifice (area a) at the bottom, as a function of time, t.

[I'll assume the surface area of the beaker to be A >> a, and the container to be extremely light]

At time t,

Let the speed of the liquid layer be u downwards, speed of the beaker be v in the backward direction and speed of the ejected fluid be $v_{0}$, then:

By the equation of continuity: $Au = av_{0}$. Further, by Bernoulli's equation between the open surface at the top and ejecting fluid at the bottom, $P_{atm} + \rho gx + \rho \frac{u^{2}}{2} = P_{atm} + \rho \frac{v_{0}^{2}}{2}$.

Using suitable approximations, we get $v_{0} = \sqrt{2g (H - x)}$.

The thrust force on the beaker at this instant, $f_{th} = \lambda v_{rel} = \rho a(v_{0} + v)^{2} = \rho a(\sqrt{2g (H - x)} + v)^{2} = \rho A(H -x) \frac{dv}{dt}$

where the final expression relates to the "m * a" of the remaining mass of the container. At this point, I am lost as to how I can possibly relate "x" and "v".